# tense of the main clause with "if only"

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

Which tense should be used in the main clause of the following?

> We **tend** / **would tend** to view the earth as capable of regulating itself, **if only** humans would stop interfering with it.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Why would the result of the *if*-clause be expressed using the simple present?  *If only humans would stop interfering with it, we **tend** to view the earth as capable of regulating itself.*   Would you say *If only it would rain, the crops **grow***?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo ESL/EFL grammar would lead me to expect "would tend to," but a native speaker used "tend to" with an if-only clause.

Comment: And some native speakers seem to endorse the "tend to" option: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tense-of-the-main-clause-with-if-only.3509838/#post-17828126

Comment: @Lambie I got conflicting answers, so I want to find out which view is correct.

Comment: Perhaps they're understanding it as two entirely separate clauses: *We tend to view the earth as capable of regulating itself—if only humans would stop interfering with it!*

Comment: By "separate clauses," are you saying they are not in a  subordinate-main clause relation?

Comment: They are not in any relationship other than being consecutive and semantically #2 is not a *non sequitur*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either is appropriate in the context.

"*We tend to*" is describing tendencies that we are known to have and still have. The problem with this in the context you give is that you go on to use a conditional clause "*if*" in respect to something that might happen in the future (we stop interfering with the earth). It doesn't make sense to say that we *tend* to do something, which is an established pattern of thought or behaviour based on the *past*, but then say that is conditional on something in the *future*.

Likewise "*We would tend to.... if...*" is problematic because you are essentially predicting a "tendency", and a tendency is something established from past behaviour.

If you are actually trying to say that we have an *existing* tendency to think that the earth *could* repair itself *if* humans stopped interfering with it, then I would suggest you phrase this as:

> We tend to **believe that** the earth **is capable** of regulating itself, if only humans would stop interfering with it.

This puts our tendency to believe or think something in the *present tense*, even though that belief is *about the future*. It also makes it clear that we believe it to be dependent on the condition stated.

Comment: The "natural" position for a conditional clause is at the *start* of an utterance, so a really simplified version of the relevant syntax would be, for example, ***If you would speak, I would listen***. According to your final suggestion above, people might say ***If you would speak, I listen*** as an alternative to my example - *but native speakers [would] never say that*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That wouldn't make any sense here. If you put the conditional clause at the start here it would say: "*If only humans would stop interfering with the earth, we would tend to view it as capable of regulating itself*". That would place the conditional clause on the *tendency*, rather than the earth repairing itself, and I do not believe that is what the OP wants to say.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "We tend to believe that the earth **would be** capable of regulating itself, if only humans would stop interfering with it"?

Comment: @Apollyon I'm not sure it matters either way. I say "is", because saying something "is capable" isn't the same as actually doing it now. With the "if" clause it is clear that this is something that would only happen should the condition be met. The condition doesn't make the earth *become* capable, it just allows it to do what it is already capable of.

Comment: @Astralbee: I don't understand what you mean by that. Unless I'm missing something, *it never affects the meaning* whereabouts (before / within / after the utterance) you put the conditional clause.

Comment: ...oic You mean *[We tend to believe that] if only humans would stop interfering with it, the earth is capable of regulating itself.* Where the optional [square bracketed] clause is irrelevant to the syntax of the rest. I still think it's a peculiarity of the *specific* assertion ***the earth is capable of regulating itself*** that we can get away with using simple present in a clause that's semantically bound to a conditional clause. Similarly, *If you would stop interfering, I **can** manage my own affairs* is "acceptable", but strictly speaking we might expect ***could***, not ***can***

Comment: I'm not *quite* sure exactly what's making the difference between the example in my first comment, and OP's (& my second example above), but I'm tempted to think that Present Tense is acceptable because it refers to something that ***was also true in the past*** (before the specified condition obtained, just as it ***would*** be true again in the future if that condition ceased to apply).